# Scroll to fixed points automatically using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an app in development, and I want it so that when the user scrolls up or down, it will lock it to the nearest anchor point.

Is there any known way of doing this? If anyone has the 'circa' app on iPhone, you'll know what I'm talking about.

I've got a simple hacked solution working that detects scrolls and does this:

```
var nearestAnchorOffset = calculateNearestAnchorOffset();
$('body').scrollTop(nearestAnchorOffset);
```

However, it's not ideal as it's quite jumpy and unpredictable sometimes.

One problem seems to be that the scroll event fires when scrolling *starts*, is there an equivalent event that fires at the end of scrolling?

Here's the site I'm trying to get it to work on:

http://supi.hmp.is.it

Note the effect is only triggered on small screens (it's not really needed on desktops). I've used a jQuery debounce on the scroll so that it only triggers when the user *stops* scrolling. It's pretty smooth on desktop, however when looking on an iPhone it doesn't get it right 50% of the time and scrolls to the wrong place.

This is my full solution so far:

```
if($( document ).width() <= 768){
    var offsets = {};
    $( window ).scroll($.debounce(function(data) {
        if(isActive !== false){          
            // different scrollable points
            offsets.todaytitle      = $('.row.today.title').offset();
            offsets.todaywind       = $('.row.today.result .wind').offset();
            offsets.todaytemp       = $('.row.today.result .temp').offset();
            offsets.tomorrowtitle   = $('.row.tomorrow.title').offset();
            offsets.tomorrowwind    = $('.row.tomorrow.result .wind').offset();
            offsets.tomorrowtemp    = $('.row.tomorrow.result .temp').offset();
            offsets.form            = $('#postcodeForm').offset();
            offsets.nav             = $('#nav-bottom').offset();
            offsets.top             = {top: 0};

            var current = $(window).scrollTop();
            var closest = "";
            var curDiff = 99999;
            $.each(offsets, function( key, value ) {
                var diff = Math.abs(offsets[key].top - current);
                if(diff < curDiff){
                    curDiff = diff;
                    closest = key;
                }
            });

            animatedScroll(offsets[closest].top);
        }
    },350));
}

function animatedScroll(offset){
    $("body").animate({ scrollTop: offset },200, function() {
        scrollingOn = false;
    });
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

You did not include what you have already tried but I can show you a solution I made just recently with this type of problem.

It's not going to be smooth handling it with `scroll()` function alone because **dragging the scrollbar** can be a big problem, I suggest you do it with **mousewheel** event.

Do the anchoring by binding it with `'DOMMouseScroll mousewheel'` event. Then get the direction of mousewheel using `originalEvent.wheelDelta`, scrolling down will return a negative value and scrolling up will be positive value.

```
$('body').bind('DOMMouseScroll mousewheel', function(e){
    var $anchored = $('section.anchored');      

    if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0) { //mousewheel down
        $next = $anchored.next();

        if($next.length){
            $('body').stop().animate({scrollTop:$next.offset().top},'slow');
            $anchored.removeClass('anchored')
            $next.addClass('anchored')     
        } 
    }else{ //mousewheel up
        $prev = $anchored.prev();

        if($prev.length){
            $('body').stop().animate({scrollTop:$prev.offset().top},'slow'); 
            $anchored.removeClass('anchored')
            $prev.addClass('anchored')   
        }
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Now if the user scrolls by dragging the scrollbar you also need to move the `'anchored'` class indicator to the most visible `<section>` in viewport.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();

    $('section').each(function(){
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        if(st >= offset.top && st < offset.top + $(this).outerHeight()){
            $(this).addClass('anchored');
        }else{
            $(this).removeClass('anchored');
        }
    });
});
```

Here is my sample [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mark_s/4MDwJ/).

Comment: Hmm this is an interesting solution - I've posted some more details on what I've tried so far and a link to the app I'm working on, if you view it in a small window or even better on an iPhone you'll see what I mean. It works fine on desktop but iPhone is giving me problems, it seems to not be firing the scroll event at the right place (it fires at the right time, but the position marked seems to be where the finger left off rather than the resting position after momentum).